# How to pass query in a dynamically created linkbutton in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wanna to pass query in a dynamic link button. I can add it dynamically but unable to pass query on that. Apart from that LinkButton_onClick handler is not working.

Pls tell me how to proeed?

Comment: Can you post the code you are having problems with? Can't tell you what's wrong without seeing what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Have you assigned the event to the button?

```
LinkButton myNewButton = new LinkButton();
myNewButton.Text = "Click me!";
myNewButton.Click += new EventHandler(this.myNewButton_Click);

protected void myNewButton_Click() {
    //do stuff here
}
```

If you've already done this, chances are you're creating the control in the wrong Page Event.